# How to properly handle In App Purchases for iOS apps and how to define the product?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I followed this [guide](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5456-in-app-purchase-tutorial-getting-started) to set up an in-app purchase in my app. I've done everything and set it up in App Store Connect. My problem is the actual purchase at the moment is simply a boolean in UserDefaults for `ArePagesUnlocked = true` But I am having trouble on where I actually define this in the product. I understand how to set up and manage the purchases and restores but where do I actually define the product as being an instruction to change the value of ArePagesUnlocked from false to true, On the Buy Button Action? I tried that but if there was no connection then the user has still unlocked it. Do I have to build this seperately and send it? I have been just getting a bit confused during my research and not found a clear answer thus far so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: code:

```
   public init(productIds: Set<ProductIdentifier>) {
    productIdentifiers = productIds
    for productIdentifier in productIds {
        let purchased = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: productIdentifier) // this i use to see if purchased
        if purchased {
            purchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(productIdentifier)
            print("Previously purchased: \(productIdentifier)")
        } else {
            print("Not purchased: \(productIdentifier)")
        }
    }
    super.init()

    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
}
}
```

Do I need to add a seperate UD Value from the one above? It seems It doesnt know its purchased until I restart the app, how can I make it instant?

```
extension IAPHelper: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case .purchased:
            complete(transaction: transaction)
            break
        case .failed:
            fail(transaction: transaction)
            break
        case .restored:
            restore(transaction: transaction)
            break
        case .deferred:
            break
        case .purchasing:
            break
        }
    }
}

private func complete(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    print("complete...")
    deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
}

private func restore(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    guard let productIdentifier = transaction.original?.payment.productIdentifier else { return }

    print("restore... \(productIdentifier)")
    deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: productIdentifier)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
}

private func fail(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    print("fail...")
    if let transactionError = transaction.error as NSError?,
        let localizedDescription = transaction.error?.localizedDescription,
        transactionError.code != SKError.paymentCancelled.rawValue {
        print("Transaction Error: \(localizedDescription)")
    }

    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
}

private func deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: String?) {
    guard let identifier = identifier else { return }

    purchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(identifier)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: identifier)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .IAPHelperPurchaseNotification, object: identifier)
}
```

Comment: You need to enable it when the purchase is properly completed. It's all related to `SKPaymentQueue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual strategy is that in your `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` you write into user defaults if the user purchases.

Comment: Thank you I see now how it works, now my problem is the value that is saved after purchase, when I go back to see if it is unlocked, the userdefaults value is not recognised to have changed unless i relaunch the app, do you know why?

Comment: Well it's also up to the relevant parts of your app to consult that user defaults setting. You're not consulting user defaults until that `init` rolls around, i.e. relaunch the app. But all parts of your app that depend on whether the user has purchased need to consult user defaults every time they do any of that functionality.

Comment: For example in my app there's a button that the user can tap, but it doesn't do anything unless the user has purchased.

Comment: I understand, it must be because I defined the var outside of the function so It did not check it again, thank you. `var pagesUnlocked = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "01")
    @objc func addButtonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        
        print("Button tapped")
        if Manager.shared.coins.contains(searchDataObject) {
            Duplicate()
        } else if Manager.shared.coins.count == 5 && pagesUnlocked == false {
            max()
        } else if Manager.shared.coins.count == 10 {
            max10()
        }  else {`

Comment: so adding `let pagesUnlocked = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "01")` inside the function should fix it